# Should we carry Tags in Titles?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to know what the community thinks on this topic for this very site.

**Should the tags (e.g., country-specific ones) exist within question titles**, or they have to be avoided for sake of clarity?

It has been discussed before:
[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

See [this edit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/posts/1082/revisions) for example — not that I disagree, but for me it would be nice to know the policy and avoid further mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

The system will automatically join popular tags to the left side of the title in the rendered HTML `<title></title>` element - this is done specifically for SEO and delivering more useful titles in search engine result listings.

It's therefore good to avoid *deliberately* adding tag words in titles, but don't break good composition purely for the sake of avoiding or including one. Here's an example:

> How do I tell if a taxi turned on its meter in The Philippines?

That's obviously going to have [philippines](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippines) attached to it, and reiterated in the title, but it's a good title.

> Philippines: How do I know if a taxi turned on its meter?

.. That's bad. You're just duplicating what the engine selectively does, and it does a *very* good job of picking the right tag to join in the title.

> How do I know if a taxi turned on its meter?

.. Also bad, because depending on how folks read, they don't know if it's a question they can or can't answer.

> How do I know if a taxi turned on its meter in Manila?

Along with [philippines](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippines) - that's the best combination. Get to the specific point as quickly as you can, you've avoided tags in titles, and now there's two locations associated with your question.

In short, don't write for SEO - let the system do it, just write titles that grab the attention of the folks likely to be able to answer the question.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The last idea sounds most reasonable. The problem is that not every SE user is familiar with SEO techniques... :)